# Trigonometry identity problems

Tags: trigonometry

Ok, so I just learned trig identities and I come across this problem that had it's answer to it, and I have no idea how they got to that answer.

Here is the problem:

$$
\frac{-\sec\theta}{1-\cos\theta}=\frac{-1-\sec\theta}{\sin^2\theta} 
$$

Now the problem calls for the left side to be adjusted. Here's where it came to first:

$$
\frac{-1-\sec\theta}{1-\cos^2\theta}
$$

After that, it then came to the solution which was:

$$
\frac{-1-\sec\theta}{\sin^2\theta} 
$$

I'm stumped on how they got to the second step. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Multiply numerator and denominator by $ (1+ \cos \theta) $ and simplify.

Answer (score 1):

$1= cos(\theta)^2 + sin(\theta)^2$
~Pythagoras
[image]